# Intel DH55TC motherboard compatible with 2 x 8GB RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have an Intel DH55TC motherboard and want to know if I can equip it with 2 x 8GB to get 16GB, or do I need to buy 4 x 4GB instead?

This are the specifications from Intel: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/000005869.html

Comment: I tried adding 2 x 8GB sticks to this board recently and it wouldn't take it. It went into BIOS fine, acted like it was OK, but then Windows freezes and boot loops. Pop original RAM in and it's fine. It could not handle even one 8GB stick. Tried very latest possible BIOS update for the board as well, no dice. The linked specs only lists a max of 4GB in their "tested memory" table, so I assume that is the limit per slot after all.

Answer (score 0):

It says "16 GB maximum total system memory (with 2 Gb memory technology)". Better safe than sorry, you should use 2 GB modules. Unless you can borrow 4 GB from someone else to test.

Comment: But how do 4 2GB strips make 16GB?

Comment: Yes, they don't. I'm going to correct myself, because I found proper specifications [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/42408/Intel-Desktop-Board-DH55TC) where it does say that maximum is 16, depending on CPU type.

Comment: But would it support 2 x 8GB, you think?

Comment: I think you should use 4x4 GB.